# Multiprocessing takes longer when using for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, multiprocessing

I just finished watching [this video on multiprocessing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOhrIov7PZA) and while playing around, got confused about a slow down that occurred when using for loop.

In the video, the following code is executed to demonstrate the speed of multiprocessing

```
    a = mp.Process(target=counter, args=(25000000,))
    b = mp.Process(target=counter, args=(25000000,))
    c = mp.Process(target=counter, args=(25000000,))
    d = mp.Process(target=counter, args=(25000000,))

    a.start()
    b.start()
    c.start()
    d.start()

    b.join()
    a.join()
    c.join()
    d.join()
```

I saw this and thought: "why not just use for loops instead? I have 16 CPU cores and don't want to write out 16 variable names"

So as a start, I changed the code to

```
    processes = []
    for i in range(1, 4):
        processes.append(mp.Process(target=counter, args=(250000000,)))
    
    for i in range(len(processes)):
        processes[i].start()
    for i in range(len(processes)):
        processes[i].join()
```

When executing this instead, the time it took was much longer compared to the time of the individual variable code (10.8 seconds versus only 1.8 seconds). Why did this happen?

Comment: You used 3 processes instead of 4 and the argument is 10 time larger.

Comment: @KlausD. has the answer, but you should also look at using https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool to simplify the code

Comment: Thanks @Anentropic, the link is very helpful. Can't believe I made an entire stackoverflow post for this.

Comment: if under the same conditions it still seems like multiprocessing is slower than a for loop consider [overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68892839/how-to-overcome-overhead-in-python-multiprocessing)

Comment: assert 25000000 != 250000000

Comment: One trick that might help in the future is that python allows an underscore in numeric literals. Defining the `arg = 25_000_000` would make it easier to see that it is different from `arg = 250_000_000`

Answer (score 0):

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def work(item):
    # Simulating some computational work
    result = item * item
    time.sleep(0.1)  # Simulating computational work
    return result

def main():
    data = list(range(1000))

    # Sequential execution
    start_time = time.time()
    results_seq = [work(item) for item in data]
    seq_time = time.time() - start_time

    # Parallel execution with multiprocessing
    start_time = time.time()
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        results_parallel = pool.map(work, data)
    parallel_time = time.time() - start_time

    print(f"Sequential Time: {seq_time} seconds")
    print(f"Parallel Time: {parallel_time} seconds")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in range(len(processes)):
    processes[i].join()
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**